# ToggleClass() jQuery is not working only on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have got one small hope obstacle.
When I click on the menu button it doesn't show the navigation (nav), but ONLY in Safari browser. In all browsers this code working properly. It is so tricky grrrr.

Here is the code: 
HTML

```
 <nav>...</nav>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#menu-open').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.main-rhomboid').toggleClass('hide');
    $('nav').toggleClass('visible');
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow');
});
```

Css:

```
.visible{
display: block;
opacity: 1;}

nav{position: absolute;
z-index: 102;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 4s;
background-color: $accent-blue;
display: none;
border: 10px solid $accent-yellow;
box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Did you check with the console if the classes are actually changed or not?

Comment: .Visible class is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: sorry, I forgot ending .visible class but only here Nawed Khan :-)

Comment: It is working on Mozilla, Opera, Chrome, but not in Safari...:O